# Can't open port 25565 for my Minecraft server

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I have the server.jar downloaded and running.
I have virtual server on my TP-Link Archer C6 up and running
I have Windows Firewall disabled.
I have even asked my provided if they blocked the port: no.
However, whenever I visit canyouseeme.org and check if port 25565 is open I get a connection timeout error.\

Can this be an ip issue? My internal ip ends with 103 and I've made it static, yet on router's configure page I found some other ip address, that doesnt begin with 192.168. And if i connect to it appending :25565 in Minecraft I connect to a server, although a friend of mine couldn't connect using it.

Also, my `server-ip` field in server.properties file is left blank and every time I launch the server.jar I get `Starting Minecraft server on *:25565` printed among the first lines.

Comment: What's the beginning of your "WAN" or "external" IP address as shown by your router?

Comment: @user1686 googling "what's my ip" gives me this 195.114...

Comment: No, I'm asking about the address shown by your router.

Comment: @user1686 oh, it doesnt say its wan. It just says "ip address". it begins with 100.64

Comment: Looks like the ISP only gives an internal (CGNAT) address to your router.

Comment: @user1686 but I was told, quote, "the ports are not blocked by provider"...

Comment: Sure, but (assuming the person you spoke with even knows that CGNAT is in use, which in itself isn't guaranteed), just because those ports are not explicitly blocked no longer means they are "open". Often with NAT in general (even if it's just 1:1 NAT) it stops being "everything can go through unless specifically blocked" and becomes the opposite – packets sent to 195.114 go nowhere _unless_ explicitly translated to the 100.64 address.

Comment: And considering that CGNAT is meant to be used when the ISP doesn't have enough IP addresses for everyone, there's a fair chance they're not doing 1:1 NAT anymore but X:1 (like your router does at home), and that you're sharing the same 195.114 address with a few other customers. Which means the ISP's CGNAT would have no way of knowing _who_ should receive the incoming packets (again, like your router not knowing which device needs to receive the packets until you set up a "virtual server" rule).